# How to have the function of presentPage on onsen ui new version 1.1.4

Tags: onsen-ui

The previous version of Onsen UI, there was a function call `presentPage`, so you could show a page without any characteristics of the previous page. It would clear the stack.

It was useful for examples, to be able to have just a page with a Sliding menu, but subsequent pages would not.

How can this in the latest Onsen UI (currently at v1.14)?

I tried using the `resetToPage` function, but that doesn't stop the Sliding menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer this one. I believe I understood the question :)

So, you have a "sliding menu" page with a main page, then a hidden menu page that could slide out when you swipe. Now you want a new page that show but doesn't have any sliding menu in it, just a regular page?

If so, you can achieve it by using ons-sliding-menu on top of an ons-nagivator

Take a look at this sample, I modified the sliding-menu code sample from onsen documentation: 'http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/EjHDk'

Link to Page2 from the menu will open up a new page without any sliding menu in it.

Give + if this helps!

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/EjHDk
```